# SharePoint Rest API Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest, api

I am using Rest API in an a web application using JavaScript, JQuery, and HTML and I'm having issues with pulling phone numbers. I have 3 phone number fields and they all show similar to this `<d:Phone_2 m:null="true" />` in the XML of this query

```
https://mysharepointsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mysharepointlist')/items?
```

They are all Single line of text fields. How can I retrieve the values?

Comment: Are you saying that the phone numbers for those items are not null and the query is specifying them as null? What is the problem exactly? What are you expecting to get?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to work with XML instead of JSON?       set ``xhr.responseType = 'json';`` (this is plain JavaScript.. I don't know the $.ajax syntax)

Comment: I found that the issue was due to the field being null in most places. I added text in the fields and it seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend you use the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool and it will give you a complete list of all the list columns and more and you can always see your mapped properties, etc... working with the REST endPoint,sometimes tricky in the browser.

Here is the link to the tool: https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/